# If condition for following set of expected outputs

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I am writing java program. i am having four boolean variables. value of which can be true/false.
I want to call 4 different web service depending on that flags.

in one go i will have only one web service call. if any two or more flags are true then i need to throw `Exception`.

Please help me to write logic.

My conditions are

```
0 0 0 0 = 0 
0 0 0 1 = 0
0 0 1 0 = 0
0 0 1 1 = 1 
0 1 0 0 = 0 
0 1 0 1 = 1 
0 1 1 0 = 1 
0 1 1 1 = 1 
1 0 0 0 = 0 
1 0 0 1 = 1 
1 0 1 0 = 1 
1 0 1 1 = 1 
1 1 0 0 = 1 
1 1 0 1 = 1 
1 1 1 0 = 1 
1 1 1 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically require a develop Karnaugh maps equation for fulfill this requirement.
The equation  for this requirement is F(ABCD)=A B + C D + B D + B C +A D +A C

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean cuSearch = false;
        boolean caseSearch = true;
        boolean cpSearch = true;
        boolean addressSearch = false;
        int e = ( ( toInt(cuSearch) * toInt(caseSearch) ) + (toInt(cpSearch) * toInt(addressSearch)) + (toInt(caseSearch) * toInt(addressSearch)) + (toInt(caseSearch) * toInt(cpSearch)) + (toInt(cuSearch) * toInt(addressSearch)) + (toInt(cuSearch) * toInt(cpSearch)) );
        boolean result=false;
        if(e == 1){
            result = true;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static int toInt(boolean b) { 
        return b ? 1 : 0 ;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
boolean one;
boolean two;
boolean three;
boolean four;

//... some logic

if( (one? 1:0) + (two?1:0) + (three?1:0) + (four?1:0) > 1) {
    // Throw exception
} else {
    // call web service based on booleans
}
```

Comment: This answer might need some explanation on the test evaluation. Adding intermediary variables will help as well.

Comment: Code is self explanatory and clear enough, in this case adding intermediate variables would mean adding unnecessary noise

Answer (score 2):

you can use following function

```
boolean flag1;
boolean flag2;
boolean flag3;
boolean flag4;

public static boolean validate(){
 int cnt = 0;
 if(flag1) 
    cnt++;
 if(flag2)
    cnt++;
 if(flag3) 
    cnt++;
 if(flag4)
    cnt++;

return (cnt>1)? true:false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a bitmask (an integer where each bit of the integer represents a boolean, and then have a bunch of enums to represent suitable sites. This would enable you to add more/less sites in the future more easily.
Code would be a little like this;

```
public enum Site {
    SITE_1(false, false, false, true), 
    SITE_2(false, false, true, false), 
    SITE_3(false, true, true false);
    private final int mask;
    Site(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d){
       this.mask=(a?(1<<3):0)+(b?(1<<2):0)+(c?(1<<1):0)+(d?1:0);
    }
    int mask(){return mask;}
}
switch(users_flags)
{
    case SITE_1:
        //do Site 1 stuff
        break;
    case SITE_2:
        //do Site 2 stuff
        break;
    case SITE_3:
        //do Site 3 stuff
        break;
    default:
        throw Exception("Invalid Site");
}
```

Comment: could you plz explain what to write in switch statement. as i am new to java i dont have much idea.

Comment: replace user_flags with whichever Site enum is passed (Site.SITE_1, Site.SITE_2, etc) is passed, that will then jump to the relevant case, so you can call your code for that site where I have the comments.

Comment: but in my case i will not be able to decide which enum i need to pass , coz i am having 4 flags whose value is set according to user's input.

Comment: Declare an enum through the constructor?

Comment: yes got it . i need to create object of enum n pass to switch condition :)